# Kubernetes postStart hook seems that blocks all the containers startup. Is that possible?

Tags: hook, kubernetes

I am in a situation where my pod is composed by 3 containers called:

- application
- collectd
- fluentd

I want that: application starts only when both collectd and fluentd are up&running ..

So I created a simple **postStart** script placed in application container, that waits forever for liveness/readiness probe of collectd and fluentd. I developed this part with the assumption that kubernetes starts in parallel all the containers and in case there is something wrong (liveness probe down) restart automatically the failing containers.

But I found two strange behaviours, strictly connected one with the other:

1. the never-ending loop in the **postStart script** (that waits for liveness of other containers) **blocks completely the spin-up of the other two**. So that fluentd and collectd have never been started.
2. **kubernetes run in alphabetical order the containers** defined inside a pod. So if I call my first container *zapplication* (instead of *application*) everything works as expected.

Now what I am asking is if this behaviour is a **feature** or is it a **bug**?

(END OF QUESTION HERE, FREE THOUGHTS ABOUT THE POSSIBLE ANSWER FOLLOW)

I read a lot of articles and discussions that state there should be no assumption in the ordering of container start, but this doesn't seem the case. Moreover among all the possible kind of ordering the alphabetical one doesn't seem to me the most deterministic one.

It also seems really strange to me that a postStart script on a container has the power to completely block the other two. But it can be also the case that this is the feature that solves the problem of dependent containers!

========================================================================
UPDATE 2/12/2016: I'll link here as a reference the issue on github
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37805

Comment: postStart runs befoe the pods are registered as running, therefore you cannot lookup the other pods by IP in the API until postStart finished. 
I guess it is a 'feature' that allows you to figure that there is no other pod of the same type running the first time you run the pod. (i.e. for example to define a master pod, while subsequent pods would be slaves...)

Comment: Well but I don't lookup the other pods by IP, I am just doing a curl on localhost with port and path where collectd and fluentd expose their readiness and liveness. I would be glad if it is a feature, the strange thing is that it is against the good practice of independent containers inside a pod!

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't know enough about the details to tell if it is normal, but as you point the containers are started in a sequence, and apparently in one thread, so that if postStart blocks, it blocks everything else.

Comment: i would report on the github project for a more detailed explanation.